# usage of "is while..."

Tags: word-usage, time, parallelism

I know this board avoids proofreading questions, but I am not sure if my question qualifies as such. Apologies if it does, but I'd very grateful for an answer.

I made a sentence whose "object/predicate" I am not sure is grammatically correct. Could you please look into it and, if it is wrong, offer suggestions for better constructions. The sentence is as follows:

> The best way to fall asleep is **while watching TV**

Is the bolded text correct, or should I construct it differently? Thanks.

Comment: That looks correct to me. What caused you to be unsure it was correct? If you were to write it a different way, what would you do differently?

Comment: That phrase after "is" seemed very...off to me. I am still in the process of learning English, so sometimes I tend to get confused about a lot things that, as I usually find later, weren't wrong to begin with. Edit: Thanks, @ColleenV, for your help.

Comment: I think rephrasing your sentence to "The best time" might work. (It's still somewhat awkward to me.) HostileFork suggestion is much better.

Comment: Thanks, @DamkerngT, for the suggestion. Could you tell me why you think it would still be awkward? I am sorry to bother; I am just trying to learn.

Comment: To me, it's more about the meaning you want to convey. (I see that you have good comments from HostileFork already. So you can simply take my comments as an aside.) Reading your question, I tried to think of "watching TV" as a way, doesn't work; *while* seemed to need time, so the cheapest fix was "The best time". But then it ran into another problem (as HostileFork explained), the underlying meanings of *while* vs. *when*. Consider: "The best time for running is in the morning." "The best time to ask for a loan is when you don't need the money."

Comment: (cont.) "The best time to look for a job is while you have one." -- Using *when* suggests a general condition, while using *while* suggests a temporary condition. Also compare: "The best time to start anything is while you still can." and "The best time to start anything is now, while you still can." Using the latter sentence works a little better for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at another sentence that might make the agreement problem a little more obvious:

> The best way to cook spaghetti is while you are in Italy.

Compare with:

> The best way to cook spaghetti is to use fresh pasta.

When you are invoking **the best way ... is** then people expect you to follow up with a **way**...not a description of a duration or a state of being.  This would also be incorrect:

> The best way to scare my cat is during a thunderstorm.

You really want to look at other ways of saying that.

> There's nothing my cat finds more frightening than thunderstorms!

It so happens that your sentence about TV is passable in this particular case.  Most wouldn't blink at it; it's "close enough for government work" (as the saying goes).

If you really want to make the case that having the TV running is the ideal way to fall asleep, when compared with all other ways, something like this would be better:

> Leaving the TV running while you nod off is the best way to fall asleep.

Comment: Ah you're right. I overlooked "best way" and focused on the object. "It's easier for me to fall asleep while watching TV." would be OK. I shouldn't post in ELL when I'm tired :)

Comment: @ColleenV As I said...I think you could generally get away with that particular sentence; didn't trip your radar as obviously wrong, and probably wouldn't for most other people...hence picking a more obviously problematic example.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing response. Learnt a lot. This, in particular, was very helpful: "When you are invoking the best way ... is then people expect you to follow up with a way". So, would it be okay if I tweaked my sentence a bit to: **The best time to fall asleep is while watching TV** or **The best way to fall asleep is by listening to soothing music**. Thanks again.

Comment: @axomna Can you say **The time to panic is while drowning**? I think **The best time to fall asleep is when you are watching TV** works better, just as I think **The best time to panic is when you are drowning** works better.  If you turn your other sentence into a Q&A as *"Q: What is the best way to fall asleep?"* and *"A: By listening to soothing music."* it calls attention to the awkwardness of `by` to start the answer, yet still, you can get away with **The best way to dine is by candlelight.**  Grey areas here! **The best way to fall asleep is to play soothing music while you drift off.**

Comment: Jeez, thank you. Clearly, there's so much learn yet.

Comment: @axomna Well it isn't math...so don't feel bad about not knowing all the weird rules--they're all made up and evolved over time!  These questions are actually really kind of hard to give satisfying answers to, because of how inconsistent the language is.  I should go back to the programming questions where I actually know the answers... but when in doubt, go with *"The best way to (X) is to (Y)"*

Comment: It is so great to know that, I assure you.

Comment: @HostileFork **"The best way to dine is by candlelight"** is a bit different though because ["by"](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/by "Merriam-Webster Learning Dictionary") doesn't mean the same thing in "by candlelight" as it does in "by doing something". In "by candlelight" it means the kind of light when something is being looked at (8b in the linked definition). For example "by the dawn's early light". It seems like the shorter a word is in English, the more definitions it has.

Comment: Huh. I'm not sure I agree with all of this. First, "while watching TV" *is* a "way" of falling asleep--not in the sense of a "method for" falling asleep, but in the more generic "style or manner" sense. So "best way is while" wouldn't be appropriate if you were trying to explain how to cure insomnia, but it might be appropriate if you're just saying under what conditions you most enjoy drifting off to sleep.

Comment: Second, I don't think "by..." is a weird way to start a description of how to do something.

Comment: @KyleStrand I do think "the best way is" puts a certain requirement on it.  Again with call and answer: *"What's the best way to fall asleep?"* => *"While watching TV."*  has an incompleteness to it that *"To do it while watching TV."* does not.  Imagine if you're not talking about the best way, but just *a* way: *"The way is while"* and *"The way is by"* do not work like *"The way is to"*.

Comment: @HostileFork Er...I don't think "to do it" solves the problem you're positing, if indeed it's even a problem; it solves the completely different problem of ensuring that the "while" clause really does function as a noun clause (by introducing it with an infinitive), but in my opinion (i.e. to my ear) it's unnecessary. Your example of "the way is [x]" doesn't quite fit, though--that's still using the definite article, and you've cut out the "to fall asleep" bit. "A nice way to fall asleep is while watching TV" doesn't sound odd to me at all.

Comment: ...though I'll admit it's not a *great* sentence. "Watching TV is a nice way to fall asleep" seems preferable.

Comment: "The best way to cook spaghetti is while you are in Italy." is a great example of a **garden path sentence** and it makes for an excellent joke.